# Using tar over ssh leads to gzip error in some cases

Tags: bash, ssh, gzip, tar

I am trying to write a bash script to retrieve files over ssh using a tar archive.

If I do it like this it works fine:

```
function sshGetFiles()
{
    tar --create --gzip --file - "file1" "file2" "file3"
}
ssh user@server "sshGetFiles" | tar --extract --gzip --file - --directory .
```

But I want to add an error message and not tar anything in case the files or directories don't exist.
So I did it like this:

```
function sshGetFiles()
{
    if ! [[ -f "file1" && -f "file2" && -f "file3" ]]; then
         echo "error, some files don't exist"
         exit 1
    fi
    tar --create --gzip --file - "file1" "file2" "file3"
}
result=$(ssh user@server "sshGetFiles")
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "${result}"
    exit 1
fi
```

And now for the cases where the files do exist, I tried to handle it in several ways, none of which worked:

```
echo "${result}" | tar --extract --gzip --file - --directory .
echo -n "${result}" | tar --extract --gzip --file - --directory .
tar --extract --gzip --file - --directory . <<< "${result}"
```

I have this kind of errors:

```
gzip: stdin has flags 0xc9 -- not supported
gzip: stdin is a a multi-part gzip file -- not supported
```

Why is it not working and how can I make it work ?

Comment: Have you tried the  `-t` flag?

Comment: I just tried it, it says: `gzip: stdin is encrypted -- not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash variables cannot hold binary data. In particular, they cannot contain null bytes. Your data is being corrupted by storing it in a variable.

You should save the output to a file.

Comment: Is it possible to save the output directly to a file on the host or do I have to save it on the remote then transfer it via ssh ? I have to enter a password every time I connect through ssh, so if I save it to a file on the remote, I would have to connect once to create the file, then a second time to retrieve it (and delete it from the remote) which is not ideal.

Comment: Apparently rsync can do some compression too, so maybe I could use it over tar ? But I'm afraid I won't be able to issue error messages with rsync.

Comment: I ended up doing `ssh "${user}@${server}" "sshGetFiles" > "result.txt"` and it worked great, thanks !